# Data Pipeline (DynamoDB to S3) - How to format S3 file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a Data Pipeline that exports my DynamoDB table to an S3 bucket so I can use the S3 file for services like QuickSight, Athena and Forecast.

However, for my S3 file to work with these services, I need the file to be formatted in a csv like so:

```
date, journal, id
1589529457410, PLoS Genetics, 10.1371/journal.pgen.0030110
1589529457410, PLoS Genetics, 10.1371/journal.pgen.1000047
```

But instead, my exported file looks like this:

```
{"date":{"s":"1589529457410"},"journal":{"s":"PLoS Genetics"},"id":{"s":"10.1371/journal.pgen.0030110"}}
{"date":{"s":"1589833552714"},"journal":{"s":"PLoS Genetics"},"id":{"s":"10.1371/journal.pgen.1000047"}}
```

How can I specify the format for my exported file in S3 so I can operate with services like QuickSight, Athena and Forecast? I'd preferably do the data transformation using Data Pipeline as well.

Answer (score 2):

Athena can read [JSON data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-JSON.html).

You can also use [DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) to stream the data to S3. Here is a link to a blog post with best practice and design patterns for streaming data from DynamoDB to [S3 to be used with Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/).

You can use DynamoDB [streams to trigger](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/) an [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function, which can [transform the data](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/619/) and store it in [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/) etc. With AWS Lambda you could also trigger [Amazon Forecast](https://aws.amazon.com/forecast/) to retrain, or pass the data to Amazon Forecast for a prediction.

Alternatively you could use [Amazon Data Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html) to write the data to an S3 bucket as you currently have it. Then use a [cloud watch event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) scheduled to run a lambda function, or an [S3 event notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) to run a lambda function. The lambda function can transform the file and store it in another S3 bucket for further processing.

Comment: So I guess it's not possible to do any kind of data transformation with data pipeline then. Did I understand this correctly, I need to set up a Kinesis Firehose stream and specify the data transformation with a Lambda function and then save the stream to an S3 file. And what's the benefit of using DynamoDB streams instead of just taking the DynamoDB table as a whole for doing data transformation?

Comment: @incnnu you can't transform with data pipeline but you can write the files to S3, and then either have a CloudWatch Event trigger a lambda, or S3 trigger a lambda to read the files and turn them into csv, and place the file in another bucket. I will update my answer